# ERROR WITH PDA'S

Tags: anchor, solana-program, client

Hi So I am trying to work with PDA and I have stumbled across an error, Initially the code did work. Later it started throwing an error , and I don't understand it .

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
    const anchorWallet = useAnchorWallet();

    async function sendTranscation() {
        if(!anchorWallet){
            return;
        }

        const network  = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";
        const connection = new Connection(network,"processed");
        const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection,anchorWallet,{"preflightCommitment":"processed"},);
        const program = new Program(idl,idl.metadata.address,provider);

        try{
            const [pda] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress([utf8.encode('legend')],program.programId);

            console.log("pda",pda);

            const trans = await program.methods.initialize(new BN(20),"value","idk").accounts({
                pdaAccount:pda,
                user:anchorWallet.publicKey,
                systemProgram:web3.SystemProgram.programId,
            }).rpc();

            console.log("Done....")
            console.log(trans);
            //const accountinfo = await program.account.pda_account.fetch(pda);
            //console.log("pda is : ",accountinfo);
        } catch (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }


    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>

            <main className={styles.main}>
                <h1 className={styles.title}>
                    Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
                </h1>

                <div className={styles.walletButtons}>
                    <WalletMultiButton />
                    <WalletDisconnectButton />
        

                </div>
                    <br>
                    </br>
                    <div >
                        <button  onClick={sendTranscation}>Create a transcations</button>
                    </div>
                <div>
                    
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

```
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, age: u64,telegram:String,name:String) -> Result<()> {
        let value =&mut ctx.accounts.pda_account;
        value.age = age;
        value.telegram = telegram;
        value.name = name;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    // We must specify the space in order to initialize an account.
    // First 8 bytes are default account discriminator,
    // next 8 bytes come from NewAccount.data being type u64.
    // (u64 = 64 bits unsigned integer = 8 bytes)
    #[account(init,seeds=[b"legend".as_ref()],bump, payer = user, space = 8 + 32)]
    pub pda_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    age: u64,
    telegram:String,
    name:String
    
}
```

ERROR
**Proxy {logs: Array(7), programErrorStack: wt, stack: 'Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction sim…ject-serum/anchor/dist/browser/index.js:74:48251)', message: 'failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation…ocessing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0'**

The above one is the error I am receiving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted in the other answer `custom program error: 0x0` is sometimes an indication that an account has already been initialized.

Comment: Yes , realized it later on.

Answer (score 0):

Since PDAs are already initiated we cant create another PDA with the same seed.